# Running async function after completion of job

Tags: python, asynchronous, cron, scheduled-tasks, discord.py

This is a flask server which also controls a discord bot.
On_ready() is the program's entry point which then takes it to my_background_task().
This function adds a cron job that runs at a specific time each day.

I want to run check_Test() , which would send appropriate message in the discord channel based on whether fn_1 or fn_2 was run by the cron job.

The problem i'm facing is i don't know how to call the check_Test() as soon as the added job in scheduler has finished.

here's the code :

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import datetime
server = flask.Flask(__name__)
test = ""

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")
channel_id = ****
channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel_id = ****
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
    scheduler.add_job(fn_1, "cron", day_of_week="mon-sat", hour=00, minute=59, second=20, replace_existing=True, id="fn_1")
    scheduler.start()
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel_id = ****
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    print("bot ready")
    await channel.send('This Bot is now Ready')
    client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())

def fn_1():
    global test
    print("running some code for fn_1")

    test = "success1"


def fn_2():
    global test
    print("running some code for fn_2")

    test = "success2"


async def check_Test():
    if(test == "success1"):
            channel_id = ******
            channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
            await channel.send('Test Has value of : Success 1')
    elif(test == "success2"):
        channel_id = ****
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send('Test Has value of : Success 2')    
client.run("****")
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that I think you should make check_Test() a task loop (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop)

```
@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def check_Test():
```

Or you should set fn_1() and fn_2() as tasks loops then at the end of the method you call check_Test().